# Remote JMX connection

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

I'm trying to open a JMX connection to java application running on a remote machine.

The application JVM is configured with the following options:

- com.sun.management.jmxremote
- com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1088
- com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
- com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

I'm able to connect using `localhost:1088` using jconsole or jvisualvm.
But I'm not able to connect using `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1088` from a remote machine.

There is no firewall between the servers, or on the OS. But to eliminate this possibility I `telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1088` and I think it connects, as the console screen turns blank.

Both servers are Windows Server 2008 x64. Tried with 64-bit JVM and 32-bit, neither work.

Comment: Probably related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151238/has-anyone-ever-got-a-remote-jmx-jconsole-to-work

Comment: Here is detailed guide http://stackoverflow.com/a/11654322/99834

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Had it been on Linux the problem would be that *localhost is the loopback interface*, you need to application to bind to your *network interface*.

You can use the netstat to confirm that it is not bound to the expected network interface.

You can make this work by invoking the program with the system parameter `java.rmi.server.hostname="YOUR_IP"`, either as an environment variable or using

```
java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=YOUR_IP YOUR_APP
```

Comment: Don't forget about `hostname -i`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11654322/99834 for details.

Comment: Worked! In our environment we use VMWare virtual machines.  The server was on a VM.  The VM was deployed fenced so it has internal and an external IP addresses.  We started the server java process with -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<external-ip-address>.

Comment: To set the host ip or change the localhost ip this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23338592/1635051) would be useful.

Comment: I have two questions here - 1) What if one wants to use JMXMP rather than JMX. What would be the configs for that? and 2) Is it possible to make the JMX connection without loading the RMI protocol?

Answer (score 75):

I've spend more than a day trying to make JMX to work from outside localhost. It seems that SUN/Oracle failed to provide a good documentation on this.

Be sure that the following command returns you a real IP or HOSTNAME. If it does return something like 127.0.0.1, 127.0.1.1 or localhost it will not work and you will have to update `/etc/hosts` file.

```
hostname -i
```

Here is the command needed to enable JMX even from outside

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1100
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=myserver.example.com
```

Where as you assumed, myserver.example.com must match what `hostname -i` returns.

Obviously, you need to be sure that the firewall does not block you, but I'm almost sure that this is not your problem, the problem being the last parameter that is not documented.

Comment: Adding -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=myserver.example.com did the trick!  Thanks!

Comment: I took the liberty of opening a JDK docs bugs for this: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8066405

Comment: "Be sure that the following command returns you a real IP or HOSTNAME. If it does return something like 127.0.0.1, 127.0.1.1 or localhost it will not work and you will have to update /etc/hosts file."

What?

Comment: Just a quick not, the `java.rmi.server.hostname=<Public DNS name from AWS EC2 console for the instance>`. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @PedroD: YOu need to an an entry to /etx/hosts with your public IP and the hostname you use for "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname"

Answer (score 28):

In my testing with Tomcat and Java 8, the JVM was opening an ephemeral port in addition to the one specified for JMX.  The following code fixed me up; give it a try if you are having issues where your JMX client (e.g. [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io) is not connecting.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8989
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8989
```

Also see [Why Java opens 3 ports when JMX is configured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884353/why-java-opens-3-ports-when-jmx-is-configured/21552812#21552812)

Answer (score 12):

http://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/troubleshooting_connection_problems_in_jconsole

If you are trying to access a server which is behind a NAT - you will most probably have to start your server with the option

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<public/NAT address>
```

so that the RMI stubs sent to the client contain the server's public address allowing it to be reached by the clients from the outside.

Answer (score 8):

it seams that your ending quote comes too early. It should be after the last parameter.

This trick worked for me.

I noticed something interesting: when I start my application using the following command line:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

If I try to connect to this port from a remote machine using jconsole, the TCP connection succeeds, some data is exchanged between remote jconsole and local jmx agent where my MBean is deployed, and then, jconsole displays a connect error message. I performed a wireshark capture, and it shows data exchange coming from both agent and jconsole.

Thus, this is not a network issue, if I perform a netstat -an with or without java.rmi.server.hostname system property, I have the following bindings:

```
 TCP    0.0.0.0:9999           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TCP    [::]:9999              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

It means that in both cases the socket created on port 9999 accepts connections from any host on any address.

I think the content of this system property is used somewhere at connection and compared with the actual IP address used by agent to communicate with jconsole. And if those address do not match, connection fails.

I did not have this problem while connecting from the same host using jconsole, only from real physical remote hosts. So, I suppose that this check is done only when connection is coming from the "outside".

Comment: What do you mean by "your ending quote comes too early"? I have the same problem, I see the TCP connection being made, but eventually jconsole claims it failed to connect.

Comment: I don't know, if I remember correctly, there was a quote open somewhere and this quote was not at the end of parameters. Maybe it was in a batch script, I can't remember. But I must admit this answer makes no sense regarding the question... Maybe the question has been edited? No edited notification under the question... I don't know, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 7):

the thing that work for me was to set /etc/hosts to point the hostname to the ip and not to the loopback interface and than restart my application.

cat /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1      localhost.localdomain localhost
192.168.0.1    myservername
```

This is my configuration:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1617 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

Comment: Yeah, it works for me too. So what does `hostname` do indeed?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks a lot, it works like this:

java *-Djava.rmi.server.hostname*=**xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx** -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=25000 -jar **myjar**.jar

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is pretty old, but there's an additional option that will help greatly. See here: https://realjenius.com/2012/11/21/java7-jmx-tunneling-freedom/

`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099`

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I tested to access JMX inside docker container

> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
>   -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=16000
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=16000 
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

Then

$ jconsole localhost:16000

Answer (score 1):

To enable JMX remote, pass below VM parameters along with JAVA Command.

```
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=453
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false                               
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
    -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=myDomain.in
```

Comment: Can you tell me why is it binding to 0.0.0.0 and not to a specific IP

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is special and mean "all ips"

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I change any hostname that matches the local host name to 0.0.0.0, it seems to work after I do that.

Answer (score -13):

Try using ports higher than 3000.