# Monitor remote WSO2 ESB using JMX

Tags: wso2, jmx, wso2-esb

I want to monitor my ESB using Jconsole and JMX. I can connect to JMX server from the localhost but for connecting from remote machine to my esb I can establish the connection.
I use WSO2 ESB 4.6 and this my `JMX configuration` in `carbon.xml` file.

```
<JMX>
        <!--The port RMI registry is exposed-->
        <RMIRegistryPort>9999</RMIRegistryPort>
        <!--The port RMI server should be exposed-->
        <RMIServerPort>11111</RMIServerPort>
</JMX>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, my rmi service was running on the host ip which was "127.0.0.1". To connect remotely to the jvm I had to bind the external ip to the hostname. To do this in unix systems use command `hostname` to get the name of the hostname. Then check the ip that is assigned to the hostname, to find out this use `ping $(hostname)` you will see that system is pinging the hosname's ip.
If your host ip was the default 127.0.0.1 and you wanted to change it, just edit the file /etc/hosts as superuser. After rebooting the rmi service, you can reach it from the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at wso2carbon.log, you will find an entry like `INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager} -  JMX Service URL  : service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11111/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager}`

Use given URL to connect to the carbon server from a remote JMX client (JVisualVM for example) and don't forget to define security credentials (default Username / Password is admin / admin)

Comment: I did this. I copied the url "service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11111/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi" in to jConsole and entered admin/admin for the credentials but it doesn't connect to the server!

Comment: You've replaced the two "localhost" inside this URL with the name of your host ?

Comment: I sure did. I repalced "localhost" with "192.168.0.97"

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. And added that as an answer.