# Cannot connect to localhost using service:jmx/rmi//..... When Using Visual VM with Tomcat within Vagrant

Tags: java, tomcat, vagrant, port, visualvm

I've got a vagrant VM which is running tomcat and I wanted to connect VisualVM to monitor the performance of the VM during some tests.

I followed [this guide](http://blog.markshead.com/1129/connecting-visual-vm-to-tomcat-7/) to setup this configuration which recommended creating a setenv.sh script and placing it within /usr/share/tomcat7/bin. I found that setenv wasn't being run, so I placed the following in /etc/tomcat/tomcat.conf instead:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true - Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9901 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

m.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9909"

I believe that the config is working as when running the following, I can see the ports active:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ netstat -lntu | grep 99
tcp6       0      0 :::9901                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::9909                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Here is my config from the vagrant file:

```
  # Ports enabled for VisualVM to work. 
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9901, host: 9905
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9909, host: 9907
```

However after entering the following config, or close variations of (have tried 127.0.0.1 & enabling "do not require SSL" all I get is " ".

I have also tried ports 9901, 9905, 9909.

[image: VisualVM Config]

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: Do you check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/834660/4165731 ?

Comment: Yeah I did, it unfortunately since the vagrant setup has a NAT network and therefore no IP I can use. I tried switching it to a bridged adapter but I couldn't get this setup to work at all.

Comment: By any chance have you configured a private address for that VBox?

Comment: This was a while ago now but I was using vagrant and tried to configure a private address and it refused to accept it.