# OpenJDK core dump from the command line?

Tags: java, debugging, coredump

Can anyone give me a hint to what I am doing wrong?

So, on Redhat (Amazon AMI Instance) , I am trying to get a core dump of my running application.  I am unable to connect to the JMX port from jconsole.exe or jvisualvm.exe from a windows box even though the remote port is wide open (and JMX server is properly configured).  I don't know why, and so I am trying to get a core dump from the JVM directly (Cntrl-\ didnt work).   So, here is how I set things up to get the core dump, but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

```
[ec2-user bin]$
jsadebugd 2504 -F Attaching to process
ID 2504 and starting RMI services,
please wait... Debugger attached and
RMI services started.
```

So, after the debugger is running, I try to create the dump using this, but it fails:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=dump.t 2504 
2504: Unable to open socket file:
target process not responding or
HotSpot VM not loaded The -F option
can be used when the target process is
not responding

[ec2-user ~]$ jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=dump.t 2504 -F 
Attaching to core -F from 
executable 2504, please wait... Error
attaching to core file: Can't attach
to the core file
```

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151238/has-anyone-ever-got-a-remote-jmx-jconsole-to-work/3256207#3256207?

Answer (score 5):

Try placing the '-F' option before PID:

```
jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=dump.t -F 2504
```