# JMX : cant connect from Windows box to monitor JMX port on a Linux system

Tags: java, jmx, remote-debugging

I have a lot of experience with jconsole.exe  and JVisualVM.exe , in the JDK1.6 and have connected thousands of times from a Windows JVM over to a Windows JVM on another machine via JMX.remote  but it fails when I try to monitor a java instance that is running on a Linux host (from a Windows host and I tried JMX listener on redhat and SUSE at Amazon EC2).   I also tried using jconsole.exe and get a similar error.

Is there any reason anyone can think of , why this kind of JMX connection would have a problem.  Any ideas I can try?  Has anyone "actually" done this and can say it will work if I persevere?

The error I get from JVisualVM (on the remote connect attempt) is something like this:

```
"Cannot connect using service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<jmx service ip>:8001/jmxrmi"
```

My remote JMX service config is like this:

```
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8001
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.hostname=<jmx service ip>
```

Found a similar question at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151238/has-anyone-ever-got-a-remote-jmx-jconsole-to-work/3256207#3256207) but it didn't answer my question.

I verified that "iptables" is not enabled as a service and is not on and so I don't imaging there is any sort of firewall blockage.   Also, both the windows and linux machine are on a 10.0.0.0 private internal subnet together.  I am able to telnet into the port 8001 to verify its there , and its listening (netstat -ap) on the linux machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the system property [java.rmi.server.hostname](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html). On your Linux server JVM, set this system property to be the public IP of the host. Then use the public IP in you client JMX URL.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that the RMI implementation is kind of hard to work with through firewalls and such as it requires more than the port you specify to work. Things you typically wouldn't notice if you connect to your own machine or a machine on the same network.
[This post describes the problems you will run into quite well](http://blog.markfeeney.com/2010/10/jmx-through-ssh-tunnel.html)

If I were you, I would try to setup jmxmp as an alternative protocol. To do so you need to add the jmxremote_optional.jar (free from Oracle, download ["JMX Remote API 1.0.1_04 Reference Implementation" from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/download-jsp-141676.html)) to both the server and the jvisualvm classpath but it is worth it.

If you google for jmxmp you will find quite a few examples on how to set things up, one of my first hits are http://pub.admc.com/howtos/jmx/distributed-chapt.html#jmxmp-sect which may be a bit too code oriented but I add it here anyway because it explains the things like like most with jmxmp in a few good sentences.

How to define the server side endpoint is depending on what you are running. Most app servers will let you type in a jmxmp enabled jmx service url but if the server is written from scratch you might have to set it up yourself in code instead of using the -D switches to java you are used to.

Give it a try and return with more specific questions about it if you run into problems.

**Edit:**
After you have added the jar to the classpath, the only thing you have to do in your code (assuming you are not using a server app that already handles it for you) is the following (omitting declarations, exception handling and such as you will figure it out anyway):

```
url=new JMXServiceURL(jmxurl);
this.server = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, null, ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());
this.server.start();
```

Comment: I verified that there is no port blockage (as i said above in my edit) but I will look at your suggestion and get back to you soon.

Comment: The problem is that it is not enough to verify that you are not blocking the port specified. There is more to it (as described in the first link). Anyway, it is possible to get it to work but jmxmp is so much easier to work with and (imho) works better over distance.

Comment: I cant find any documentation on what the "-D" args should be , to the JVM, to get the JMXMP listener going. Or, does it not work unless I implement it in code , such as the way that Jetty implemented it in code via their config files?

Comment: @djangofan I don't think there are any -D args as it is an optional add on and the JVM doesn't know how to handle it by default. If you are running a jetty, tomcat or such just adding a correct service URL would work. If you have written the server by yourself you probably need to create the listener in code as well (which is what I would suggest even for the RMI listener but that's another story).
Edit: Updating the post to show you how.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like the way to go.  It might take me a week or so to resolve this , but thanks.  I'll award points later.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating an SSH tunnel to the Linux box from your Windows machine? http://oldsite.precedence.co.uk/nc/putty.html

Or if you have cygwin, just try `ssh -f your-user@remote-server.com -L 7777:remote-server.com:123 -N` where `7777` is the port on YOUR windows machine, and `123` is the port on the remote Linux box that listens to JMX commands.

With either of the above, you can use jconsole or visualvm on your Windows box and connect to `localhost:7777`.

I know iptables is disabled, but just confirm that JMX is working fine at that port by SSHing into the Linux box and trying to use commandline JMX mode of jconsole for localhost (on the Linux box).

Comment: I'm using Bitwise Tunnelier SSH client to setup the client-to-server port forwarding.  Still can't get it working but I'll fiddle with it some more because it seems hopeful...

Comment: To confirm your port-forwarding technique works, just try to use it with some port on the remote server that you know works.Like an Apache instance running at port 80 which you can access from that box's command line using `curl http://localhost`. Once you know that port works, try to setup a tunnel/port-forward from your windows box, and see if you're able to access it. This way, you know port forwarding is working for you, and can limit the scope of the problem to the JMX server.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually just tackled this problem myself and figured it out.

I would wager that the problem is the RMI connections - you can't predict which ports it will use and so you can't get it to work with a firewall.

The workaround is to use an SSH proxy:

1. SSH to the box where your application is running but use the -D option like this:

   ssh user@remoteHost -D 9999

   As you are on Windows, you can use Cygwin to run the command above, or you can do the same thing with Putty through the GUI (guide here: http://blog.ashurex.com/2012/03/15/creating-ssh-proxy-tunnel-putty/)

   This will start a socks proxy on your local machine on port 9999.
2. Open JVisualVM and in the preferences, under 'network' configure it to use a socks proxy at localhost, on port 9999.

If you do the above, you should then be able to connect to the remote machine as normal and since all the RMI traffic is now going over the SSH proxy, it is punched through the firewall and works nicely.

Good luck :-)