# Profiling Java application in kubernetes

Tags: java, docker, profiling, kubernetes

I want to profile my play application on my Kubernetes cluster.

I am using VisualVM, and the steps that I have taken are as follows:

1. Image is built on ubuntu latest
2. Running my play application with the following args:

   ```
   "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote",
   "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false",
   "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false",
   "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1098"
   ```
3. My Image has `apt-get install -y visualvm`
4. I do `kubectl port-forward <Container> 1098`
5. Open VisualVM, And I don't see the process.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. When running the application on localhost (not via IDE, straight from the startup script) everything works fine.

**Update 1, deployment and service**

> ```
> apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
> kind: Deployment
> metadata:
>   name: myApp
>   labels:
>     name: myApp
> spec:
>   replicas: 1
>   strategy:
>     rollingUpdate:
>       maxSurge: 1
>       maxUnavailable: 0
>     type: RollingUpdate
>   template:
>     metadata:
>       name: myApp
>       labels:
>         name: myApp
>     spec:
>       containers:
>       - name: myApp
>         image: ...
>         args: ["-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1098"]
>         ports:
>         - containerPort: 9000
>         env:
>         ...
> ```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myApp
  labels:
    name: myApp
spec:
  selector:
    name: myApp
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 9000
```

**Update 2 @marcospereira**

File->Add JMX connection-> localhost:1098

Cannot connect to localhost:1098 using service jmx:rmi...

Comment: Can you add your deployment & service definitions?

Comment: That is because, when you run locally, visualvm know how to recognize the local Java processes. You need to add a "JMX Connection" (File -> Add JMX Connection).

Answer (score 6):

It can be executed in the same form as QA below.

[multiple app nodes how to expose jmx in kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184558/multiple-app-nodes-how-to-expose-jmx-in-kubernetes)

Please set `java.rmi.server.hostname` System Property.

```
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote",
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false",
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false",
"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1098"
"-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1" #add
```

Jmx connect to `localhost:1098` .

I confirmed that I could connect.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the rmi port option too -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1098

Answer (score 1):

You need to run below command to port forward in a correct manner:

kubectl port-forward ${pod_name} 1098:1098

In visualvm, add jmx connection with localhost:1098.

Add below parameters to enable jmx connection in your java options,

```
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1098
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1098
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
  -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
```