# Cannot connect to JMX/RMI server with VisualVM for no apparent reason

Tags: java, rmi, jmx, visualvm, jvisualvm

I have my OSGi application launching with the following command in my remote machine:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8080 \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
  -jar bin/felix.jar
```

And in my local machine I have VisualVM from which I try to connect to the remote JVM instance:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your JVM up and running when you try to connect to JVM?

Comment: By default, the jmx connector listener binds to the localhost interface.

Comment: I launch java with the command I posted above, then I try to connect using VisualVM as you can see.

If I launch java in the same machine I have VisualVM it detects the JVM instance instantly, so I can't understand why it fails remotely, though locally I don't need to put those -Dcom flags.

Comment: @Nicholas what do you mean? What do I need to change to make it work?

Comment: Try adding -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=sb-prd.tagus.ist.utl.pt (or whatever the hostname of your remote server is). For more info see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151238/has-anyone-ever-got-a-remote-jmx-jconsole-to-work

Comment: What if the server has dynamic IP? This option should make 0 difference... I'll try it anyway.

Answer (score 7):

The comment from @Klara saved my day !!
fixed my connection to the jstad

```
jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=all.policy -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=hostname-goes-here &
```