# Connection Failed:Connection refused:connect on remotely accessing jconsole for tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jconsole

I have a web application deployed on tomcat, I connected jconsole with tomcat by adding setenv.sh file in bin folder of tomcat with following settings:-

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote       
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port={portno}
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname={ip}"
```

here, ip is of the system where tomcat is installed and application is deployed.
Locally jconsole is workinf fine but can't connect it remotely from other system.

Continuously getting connection failed connection refused error.

Comment: is your remote system behind a firewall or a proxy , or might have a network map configured in order to accept remote requests only on port 8080? also change this line `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true`

Comment: how to know about the network mapping for remote request  and how to allow 9999 port for request?

Comment: just guide for atleast the simple remote access without authentication and without enabling SSL

Comment: I also added this com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port  taking help from the following ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151238/has-anyone-ever-got-a-remote-jmx-jconsole-to-work but still connection failed refused error

Comment: have you added this line `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true` ??

Comment: where i am going wrong. I have also put off the firewall still the other system is not able to access the jconsole

Comment: to test a service connection you can use a tool like telnet , to test the specified port. also , the ip you are configuring for the jmx , is a known ip for your machine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89032/discussion-between-testing-test-and-antjavadev).