# Cannot set Debug to work for Java via Dockerized WebLogic, not with intelliJ nor Studio Code

Tags: java, docker, debugging, yaml, weblogic12c

I want to attach the Debugger to my deployed WARs in my dockerized WebLogic 12c.
I use this official image of WebLogic (which is a Linux container)
https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-weblogic-server-12c
and I start the container using docker command:

```
docker run -d -p 4002:4002 -p 9002:9002 
-v c:/my-path-to-shared-volume:/u01/oracle/properties 
-e ADMINISTRATION_PORT_ENABLED=true -e DOMAIN_NAME=docker_domain 
-e JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=\"-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=4002,server=y,suspend=n\" 
--name weblogic store/oracle/weblogic:12.2.1.3-dev-200109
```

The weblogic console comes alive at https://localhost:9002/console/ but when trying to run the debugger, my IDE says:

> Unable to open debugger port (localhost:4002): java.io.IOException
>   "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"

My OS is Windows10. I tried with **Visual Studio Code** ***and*** **IntelliJ**, and got the same output. The WARs run just fine and they respond when I use portman to hit some service endpoints.

What seems to happen is that weblogic start scripts inside the container tries to apply the Java Options param twice! Please see the relative parts of container output below:

> Domain Home is:  /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/docker_domain
>   **Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS**: "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:4002,server=y,suspend=n"
>   *Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 4002*
>   Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
>   Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

[...]*(and further down in the logs I get: )*

> Starting WLS with line:
>   /usr/java/jdk-8/bin/java -server   -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -cp /u01/oracle/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic-launcher.jar -Dlaunch.use.env.classpath=true -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=/u01/oracle/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.policy  -Djava.system.class.loader=com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader  -javaagent:/u01/oracle/wlserver/server/lib/debugpatch-agent.jar -da -Dwls.home=/u01/oracle/wlserver/server -Dweblogic.home=/u01/oracle/wlserver/server      weblogic.Server
>   **Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:** "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:4002,server=y,suspend=n"
>   ERROR: transport error 202: **bind failed: Address already in use**
>   ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
>   JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
>   Stopping Derby server...
>   Derby server stopped.

I then tried to work with docker-compose, creating a .yaml file to add my environmental props there, trying to prevent these from running twice. I got the exact same behavior. Whichever port I use, it is found *Already in use*.

This is my .yaml file

```
version: '2'
services:
  weblogic:
    container_name: weblogic_yamled
    image: store/oracle/weblogic:12.2.1.3-dev-200109
    ports:
        - "7001:7001"
        - "7002:7002"
        - "4002:4002"
        - "4003:4003"
        - "9002:9002" 
    volumes:
        - c:/my-path-to-shared-volume:/u01/oracle/properties
    environment:
        - ADMINISTRATION_PORT_ENABLED=true
        - DOMAIN_NAME=docker_domain
        - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=localhost:4002"
```

Finally, I tried `transport=dt_shmem` but then I got a different error:

> ERROR: transport library not found: dt_shmem

Do not know what else I should try!

Comment: Is port 4002 exposed in the image and can you telnet to port 4002 on the host?

Comment: yes, both 4002 and 9002 are open

Comment: So you Can reach the debugger listening on the port from the host?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yeap.. telnet and tcping responds fine

Comment: Have you manage to solve this?

Comment: @ManolisPap no, I stopped trying and found a different way to go

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `address=*:4002` instead of `address=4002`

Comment: Thx for answer. Same behavior: java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"

Answer (score 1):

`JAVA_OPTS` is a Tomcat specific environment variable

In Java 8 the JDK supports a `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable so to enable the debugger. Try replace `JAVA_OPTS` with `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`

You also have to setup the address like this: `address=*:8000`, `address=localhost:4002` or `address=0.0.0.0:4002`

Comment: Yes, I tried all address=localhost:4002, address=*:4002 and address=4002

Comment: I've edited my answer, that might solve your problem @JohnPan

Comment: Thanks for the update. It still won't connect but I will update me question with new findings

Comment: I did the update. Pls note that none of the multipitch address syntax is accepted. So I stick with `address=4002`

Comment: @JohnPan, have you tried run docker with 
`docker run -d -p 9002:9002`

Comment: If you mean without exposing the 4002 via the -p param, yes I did. Same error: `bind failed: Address already in use`. If you read the logs you can tell that it is the JavaOpts that runs two times

Comment: Haven't used weblogic in ages. If memory serves right, there should be a catalina.sh, maybe you can have  a look inside it and see how it starts the call? Also, have you tried changing port?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with attaching a memory monitoring tool (JVisualVM). 
I could telnet to the server but that was not the whole story.

From what I have understood what was blocking me was the RMI connection used under the hoods. What was missing was a "tunnel" between client (where your debugger runs) and host (where your application runs) machine.

In windows you would open a cmd and give:

```
putty.exe -ssh <username>@<remote-host> -L <port>:<remote-host>:<same_port_again>
```

This will open a putty window which should remain open after logging in for the tunnel to remain open.

For more information on this, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151238/has-anyone-ever-got-a-remote-jmx-jconsole-to-work) on the 2nd step of the solution provided by @freedev.

I am not sure if it works for you but I suspect it may be the same case as mine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the WebLogic server in the container is configured to run in production mode (the value of the PRODUCTION_MODE variable in the script setDomainEnv.sh is set to "true").

To disable this You need open the file setDomainEnv.sh, find `PRODUCTION_MODE="true"` and change it to `PRODUCTION_MODE="false"`.

You also don't need to set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS variable, setDomainEnv.sh script already has the possibility to start in debug mode.
To enable the debug mode, the environment variable “debugFlag” needs to be set to true before executing the script.

Docker command:

```
docker run -d --name weblogic -p 7001:7001 -p 9002:9002 -p 55195:55195 
-v c:/my-path:/u01/oracle/properties 
-e ADMINISTRATION_PORT_ENABLED=true -e DOMAIN_NAME=base_domain 
-e debugFlag=true -e DEBUG_PORT=55195 
store/oracle/weblogic:12.2.1.3
```

Note, I also change the debug port to 55195.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the port number + 3 (4005) instead? That's a common practice to have a separate debug port for containerized applications

Comment: same behavior I am afraid

Answer (score 0):

use `-Xrunjdwp:transport` instead of `-agentlib:jdwp=transport`

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=*:8787,server=y,suspend=n
```